# Have image from drawable folder show up in listview using simplecursoradapater

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, simplecursoradapter

What I want to do is have an image from my `drawable-dbimages` folder show up in an ImageView using a SimpleCursorAdapter.

I really have no clue how to go about doing this. I know how to get the image by its name in the database using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`, but I don't know how to apply this to the adapter.

For example, lets say I have a table called `cars`. In that table, I have a column called `image`. The value of `image` for each row is the name of the image in the `drawable-dbimages` folder.

Now I have this code:

```
cursor = datasource.fetchAllCars();
to = new int[] { R.id.listitem_car_name, R.id.listitem_car_image };
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem_car, cursor, columns, to, 0);
setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Where `R.id.listitem_car_name` is a textview, and `R.id.listitem_car_image` is an imageview.

I know how to get the value of the `image` from the database and spit it out into a textview, but I want this to have the image from the drawables folder, whose name is in the database column, show up in the imageview for each listview item.

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android's pre-made `SimpleCursorAdapter` is built supporting only `TextViews` and mapping cursor columns to them. For what you're describing, you need to make your own adapter object, here i used a `CursorAdapter`, which is going to require to getting your hands dirty with a little bit of behind the scenes work. Here's the primary instantiation in my sample:

```
    cursor = datasource.fetchAllCars();
    dataAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
    setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Then the full blown object here

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // do the layout inflation here
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_car, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        // do everything else here
        TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem_car_name);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem_car_image);

        String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_TEXT")); 
        txt.setText(text);

        // where the magic happens
        String imgName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_IMAGE"));
        int image = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        img.setImageResource(image);
    }

}
```

I hope it's mostly self-explanatory, but the part where i labelled "where the magic happens" should be most important part pertaining to your question. basically, you get the image name from the database, and the next line tries to find the image by name (rather than by id like usual), then you simply set the image like usual. The method returns `int 0` for images it can't find, so you might or might not want to perform error-handling for that. Moreover, if you'd like to use other methods of loading your image, that'd be the spot to do it.